# Iterate over json object/ json string and get only those values present in the array

Tags: bash, jq

I have a simple requirement, where in I want to output the value of each title and score from the sample json,
I want to iterate over the metrics array and for each entry of the array, I want to look into the json_input and get the value of score from it.

```
json_input='{
    "performance": {
      "title": "Performance",
      "score": 0.95
    },
    "accessibility": {
      "title": "Accessibility",
      "score": 1
    },
    "bestPractices": {
      "title": "Best Practices",
      "score": 0.92
    },
    "seo": {
      "title": "SEO",
      "score": 0.83
    },
    "progressiveWebApp": {
      "title": "PWA",
      "score": 0.33
  }
}'

metrics=("accessibility" "bestPractices" "performance" "progressiveWebApp" "seo")

# iterate over metrics array and get the score from json_input

for metric in "${metrics[@]}"; do
  echo "${metric}" 

done
```

Comment: Do you have jq installed?

Comment: What is the result output? Should it be returned as a JSON list or other?

Comment: @Inian yes I have jq installed, the output will simply log the values

Comment: Well then `$ echo "$json_input" | jq ".$metric.score"`

Answer (score 0):

With jq, you could read in the values of the `metrics` array using the `--args` option, then reference them with `$ARGS.positional[]`, and extract the desired values from the input data in `$json_input` using `.[…].score` and the `-r` flag:

```bash
jq -r '.[$ARGS.positional[]].score' --args "${metrics[@]}" <<< "$json_input"
```

```
1
0.92
0.95
0.33
0.83
```

Back in Bash, you could then take that output, and iterate over each line for further processing. For example:

```bash
while read -r score
do printf "Score: %s\n" "$score"
done < <(
  jq -r '.[$ARGS.positional[]].score' --args "${metrics[@]}" <<< "$json_input"
)
```

```
Score: 1
Score: 0.92
Score: 0.95
Score: 0.33
Score: 0.83
```